# Jackson: Unresolved forward references when trying to deserialize JSON into java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have been stuck on a problem with `Jackson` for quite some time now and I'm eager to solve it. I have a `JSON` that has objects in it that reference to each other with ID's and I need to deserialise it into objects, but I keep getting `Unresolved forward references exception` when trying to do so.

I have tried using the `Jackson` annotation `@JsonIdentityInfo` above classes in question but this did not yield any results.

**Example of the JSON:**

```
{
  "customer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Jane Gallow",
      "age": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "John Sharp",
      "age": 20
    },
  ],
  "shoppingcart": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "customer": 2,
      "orderDate": "2015-02-19"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Customer class**

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id",scope = Customer.class)
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public class Customer {

    private int id = -1;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    //getters, setters
}
```

**ShoppingCart class**

```java
<!-- language: java -->

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id",scope = ShoppingCart.class)
public class ShoppingCart {

    private int id = -1;

    private Customer customer;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate orderDate = LocalDate.now();

    //getters, setters
}
```

I expect `Jackson` to give me a `ShoppinCart` object, that has a reference to `Customer` object in with id of `2` (John Sharp in this case). But I just can't get it to work and it gives me `"main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference` when I try to read from JSON with `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`JsonIdentityReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityReference.html) on property.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = ShoppingCart.class)
class ShoppingCart {

    private int id = -1;

    @JsonIdentityReference
    private Customer customer;
    private LocalDate orderDate;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Customer.class)
class Customer {

    private int id = -1;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Pojo.class));
    }
}
```

For your `JSON` prints:

```
Pojo{customers=[Customer{id=1, name='Jane Gallow', age=16}, Customer{id=2, name='John Sharp', age=20}], shoppingCarts=[ShoppingCart{id=1, customer=Customer{id=2, name='John Sharp', age=20}, orderDate=2015-02-19}]}
```

See also:

- [Jackson JSON - Using @JsonIdentityReference to always serialize a
  POJO by id](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-reference.html)
- [baeldung.com - More Jackson Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to a solution. I found out your example code worked, but my code in my app didn't. The difference was, I was creating the Pojo object in a little different way, which Jackson object reference algorithm obviously didn't like.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Unresolved Forward Reference during deserialization. I used the example provided on https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-reference.html to check and solve my problem.
There is a very simple class:

```
public class Order {
  private int orderId;
  private List<Integer> itemIds;
  private Customer customer;
....
}
```

I added @JsonCreator static factory method to the Customer class and it did not cause any problems.

Now when I add any kind of @JsonCreator (a static method or a constructor) to the Order class I immediately get unresolved forward reference. What is interesting, when I add the following constructor, with only @JsonPropery annotations present:

```
 public Order(@JsonProperty("orderId") int orderId, @JsonProperty("itemIds") List<Integer> itemIds, @JsonProperty("customer") Customer customer) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
    this.itemIds = itemIds;
    this.customer = customer;
}
```

it also causes unresolved forward reference.

To solve the problem, for Order class you MUST create parameterless constructor (can be private). Otherwise you will get:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.logicbig.example.Order` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

and there MUST not be any of @JsonCreator annotated methods and constructors, or constructors with @JsonProperty annotations.

And that is all.